# Spotfire-Ironpython: Read the 'Color by' properties

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

Working on TIBCO Spotfire Desktop v.7.0.0. I have a ScatterPlot where the data points are classified using the 'Color By' feature. In 'Color By', properties are manually selected.

The goal I am trying to achieve is simply to print out these properties using an IronPython program.

So far, this is my attempt:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import ScatterPlot

page = Document.ActivePageReference
for visual in page.Visuals:
    if visual.TypeId.Name == 'Spotfire.ScatterPlot':
        v = visual.As[ScatterPlot]()

        # Here I want to print the 'Color By' properties

        # print all attributes of the ColorAxis
        print(dir(v.ColorAxis))

        # I tried to read the properties of the ColorAxis using the GetProperties() attribute as follow: 
        axis = v.ColorAxis 
        print(axis.GetProperties()) 

        # What I get is something like:    
        <Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals.Axis+ <Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataProperties.IDefinesImplicitDataProperties.GetPropertyNames>d__8 object at 0x0000000000000040 [Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals.Axis+<Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataProperties.IDefinesImplicitDataProperties.GetPropertyNames>d__8]>
```

While I am expecting to get the property (column) names I set using the 'Color by' filtering. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a Line chart? Bar chart? Are the axis Continuous or Categorical? Do you want to set the colors too? What is the expression of the Color Axis? All of this is information that will determine how to write the python script.

Comment: you really do need to put more effort into asking questions. please read StackOverflow's article on How to Ask a Question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

this nugget of code will display all of the readable properties of the Color axis of a bar chart. if you need more specific information, please edit your question with more details.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import BarChart

v = viz.As[BarChart]()

print dir(v.ColorAxis)
```

Comment: Thanks niko! I tried to read the properties of the ColorAxis using the GetProperties() attribute as follow: 
    axis = v.ColorAxis
    print(axis.GetProperties())

What I get is something like:
    <Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals.Axis+    <Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataProperties.IDefinesImplicitDataProperties.GetPropertyNames>d__8 object at 0x0000000000000040 [Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals.Axis+<Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataProperties.IDefinesImplicitDataProperties.GetPropertyNames>d__8]>

While I am expecting to get the property (column) names I set using the 'Color by' filtering.
Any ideas?

Comment: please read this link and then edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve